# can not insert, update, delete mysql in IIS

Tags: php, sql

i have installed mysql, phpmyadmin, php.
it works fine.
the problem i can't insert, update, my database trough html and php.
but if i inser, update, or delete trough phpmyadmin, it is fine.
username and passwd in php or my html is same with mysql.
could you help me ho to fix this?

Comment: can you post your php code?

Comment: i have tested my php code with xampp, and it works fine.

Comment: and why do you blame IIS? php uses xampp or apache servers

Comment: i am not blame IIS, just asking here to help solve my problem.
i am new with IIS configuration.
php, sql, and phpmyadmin works fine in IIS. Just can't insert, delete, etc. only allow select arg from php.

Comment: have you seen this article? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-on-iis/install-and-configure-mysql-for-php-applications-on-iis-7-and-above

Comment: Please post your code.